# text element should not change parent element width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```css
.root {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-wrap: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <div class="root">
    <div>
      <p class="p1"> Some very long text that changes parent element width random text </p>
      <Dropdown/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="p2"> short text</p>
      <Dropdown/>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem here is for long text it increases the size of its parent div and the ratio of 1:1 changes , if i use overflow:hidden in the parent div then the dropdown doesnt work properly as this also gets hidden due to overflow:hidden property , how can i fix this so that the ratio is not distorted.

Comment: Not posting that as an answer since I don't have the knowledge to back it up, but as a workaround I've seen that using `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;` [solves the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/k1n5r6ug/).

Comment: min-width: 0 to the parent element also fix this in addition to the duplicate solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the columns to have a minimum with of 0

```css
.root {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: 80vw;
}

p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.p1 {
  background: pink;
}

.p2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div>
    <p class="p1"> Some very long text that changes parent element width random text </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="p2"> short text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="root">
  <div>
    <p class="p2"> short text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="p1"> Some very long text that changes parent element width random text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```